# View HTML page as Media print

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

Is there any possibility to view html page as media print?

My current page is too wide and If I press ctrl+p then printing page is just fine. Is possible to view printing page as a shown page instead of "too wide" page?

Is it possible?

EDIT:
Let say we have [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190316185557/http://www.jonathantneal.com:80/blog/the-html5-invoice/) page. Yoo see it like this:
[image: without ctrl+p]

If you have google chrome and press ctrl+p you will have this preview:
[image: with ctrl+p, google chrome]

How can I view second page (with ctrl+p) from the begining, so html layout would be media print?

Comment: Your Question is not clear Friend. Edit with Updated Question.

Comment: @Deekey I updated my post with images.

Comment: The images appear to look the same. What are we meant to be seeing?

Comment: Please look again. I copy the same link in both images, sorry for that.